# C# How to parse an Object[] to find all List<Int> objects using Linq?

Tags: c#, arrays, linq, parsing, object

Using Linq in C#, how would you query an `Object[]` (`data`) so that it returns all `List<int>` objects in the array and flattens them into a single `List<int>`?

This is what I tried, but for some reason it is not working:

```
List<int> IntData;

IntData = data.Where(n => n.GetType().IsGenericType)
              .Where(n => n.GetType().GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(List<int>))
              .Select(n => (List<int>) n)
              .SelectMany( n => n));
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use Linq's `OfType` method to do this:

```
List<int> IntData = data.OfType<List<int>>()
                        .SelectMany(i => i)
                        .ToList();
```

You could even make it more generic to accept *any* `IEnumerable<int>`:

```
List<int> IntData = data.OfType<IEnumerable<int>>()
                        .SelectMany(i => i)
                        .ToList();
```

Comment: Your code does not seem to deliver the expected performance (as I understood it: example in my answer).

Comment: @varocarbas I think you misunderstood what the source list contains.

Comment: Apparently I did. Will delete my answer. But I insist that my approach can deal with any situation.

Comment: @varocarbas it can't deal with `List<int>` objects which is what the question specified.

Comment: (bit late here...) Yes, actually didn't account properly for the exact OP's requirements. The whole point of my answer was showing the TryParse altenative as opossed to what you both were doing with the Int type. I should have written a better code.

Answer (score 1):

I'm on the phone with a bit limited editing capability right now, but I think this will do what you need:

```
data.OfType<List<int>>().SelectMany(x=>x).ToList();
```

Comment: As clarified in D Stanley's question, the whole point of my comment was highlighting the TryParse to account for every eventuality (instead of just Int). My code was delivering exactly what was expected, this is true; my bad. In any case, thanks for commenting back.